# A question regarding function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

While studying chapter on functions I encountered this.

$a^x ; 0 <a<1$ or $1<a$

My concern is why $a$ is not smaller than $0$?

Comment: It could be, of course it could be, but then while dealing with negative numbers you run the risk of being dragged into the complex numbers if the exponent $x$ is non-integral.

Comment: When $a < 0$, $a^x$ can be defined as a real number only when $x$ is rational with an odd denominator. In other cases, it is a complex number.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is smaller than $0$, then $a$ could be written as $-b$ where $b$ is larger than $0$. Thus, $a^x= (-1)^x*b^x = b^x$ if x is even and $-b^x$ if x is odd.

Knowing about positive $a$ is therefore sufficient enough knowledge to solve for negative as well.

Then again, I am assuming you meant $x$ is a natural number.

Even when $x$ is not an integer, $a^x= (-1)^x*b^x$ when $a<0$ is true. So, you just need to understand how $-1$ works with powers to know for every other negative number. That will be dealt separately and not in the chapter you are studying.